# Error en consola con los context de react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un proyecto en react y quería hacer un context para las alertas, todo iba bien y de hecho en la consola de Visual Code no me da ningún error pero cuando abro la pestaña del navegador donde estoy trabajando tengo varios errores en la consola y no entiendo específicamente de que es ya que no dice exactamente, creo que es algo con los context pero no doy en mi error. Este es el error que me sale en la consola del navegador [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] todos los errores en el `index.js:1`

Este es mi context de Alerta

```
const AlertaState = (props) => {
    const initialState = {
        alerta: null,
    };

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(alertaReducer, initialState);

    //Funciones
    const mostrarAlerta = (msg, categoria) => {
        dispatch({
            type: MOSTRAR_ALERTA,
            payload: {
                msg,
                categoria,
            },
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: OCULTAR_ALERTA,
            });
        }, 5000);
    };

    return (
        <AlertaContext.Provider
            value={{
                alerta: state.alerta,
                mostrarAlerta,
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </AlertaContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default AlertaState;
```

Este es mi context

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const AlertaContext = createContext();

export default AlertaContext;
```

y acá mi APP

```
function App() {
    return (
        <ProyectoState>
            <TareaState>
                <AlertaState>
                    <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                            <Route exact path="/nueva-cuenta" component={NuevaCuenta} />
                            <Route exact path="/proyectos" component={Proyectos} />
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </AlertaState>
            </TareaState>
        </ProyectoState>
    );
}
```

Comment: lee el error que te menciona la consola.

Comment: Si mano, ya lo hice pero no entiendo a que se refiere exactamente

Comment: ¿Donde estás usando `<AlertaContext.Consumer>` en tu aplicación?

Comment: Me imagino que se refiere a <AlertaContext.Provider> porque en ningún lado estoy usando ese .Consumer